# Сравнение массивов js?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, есть два массива arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7] и arr = [1,7] как их сравнить так, что бы если совпадение все были то тру, а если хоть одно не сходить то false

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Непонятно. Надо больше примеров. `[1,2],[1,2]` `[1,2],[1,2,3]`, `[1,2,3],[1,2]`, `[1,2], [1,3]` - что должно получиться?

Comment: Еще интересуют случаи `[1,2],[2,1]` и `[1,2],[1,1,2]`.

Answer (score 4):

К ответу @MoloF. every + includes

```js
const arrayFirst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7];
const arraySecond = [1,7];

const result = arrayFirst.every(item => arraySecond.includes(item));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arrayFirst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7];
const arraySecond = [1,7];

const result = arrayFirst.map(item => !!arraySecond.find(i => i === item));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: А не красивее будет every + includes использовать?

Comment: @DmitriiSedov , моих знаний в ЯП хватило только на `map` и `find`, `includes` не слышал и не использовал ранее. Оставьте свой ответ с данной функцией

Comment: оставил ответ ниже!

Comment: тогда уж indexOf надо было

Comment: @Grundy в нем тогда придется `!== -1` а это лень и не так красиво))) а вычислительная сложность там вроде одинаковая если не ошибаюсь

Comment: @DmitriiSedov, одно условие вместо некрасивого `!!` и вызова функции `i => i === item` :)

Comment: const arrayFirst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7];
const arraySecond = [1,7];

const result = arrayFirst.every(item => arraySecond.includes(item));

console.log(result); дело в

Comment: @Grundy я про ответ ниже)

Comment: @DmitriiSedov, у меня он выше :)

Comment: Я думаю, что по условии  задачи нужно было написать функцию, что возвращает true, если все элементы одного массива имеют эквивалентно соответствующий в другом.

Comment: @АлександрЛесив ну так поэтому два ответа и выставлены, я предложил один ответ, а Дмитрий другой, автор сам выберет подходящий, я просто по-другому воспринял вопрос и дал ответ на него.